# Getting a link to an answer

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason we have to click 'Share' in order to get a link to an answer? What happened to the old `Link`? It was so convenient!

Comment: I think this way is a little easier; instead of right-clicking and needing to choose "Copy link location", I can Left-click and simply hit Control-C. To me, that's easier and faster.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yes, Ctrl+C is convenient, but I suppose I have a different workflow. Right-click, copy link location is fast.

Comment: I can be wrong, but what is different from the 'share' or 'link' button? I didn't noticed the difference

Comment: @WouterJ: It was just a link to the answer, like a `bookmark` link

Comment: @0A0D you can still do it, the "share" is ordinary link that you can right click and choose "Copy link address". There is also JavaScript in action that cause left click to pop up the box, but it's just an extra layer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Ah, but that's my point. I don't want the extra layer. Just me a link ! :)

Comment: @0A0D you mean you want left click on "share" to open the link instead of showing the small pop up window?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nope, just want the old Link link back, so I can right-click, copy. I don't care about the Populist or Announcer badges which is what the Share option is trying to promote.]

Comment: @0A0D like I said, "share" **is** the good old "link" just with extra features.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Well, sort of. Its a way to push the badges.

Answer (score 4):

By clicking 'Share', you get a link that is formatted as: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/<answer id>/<your user id>` for answers and `http://stackoverflow.com/q/<question id>/<your user id>` for questions

By doing this, the system can track how many visitors were sent to an answer or question via a link by a particular user. This is used to count referrals by users and award the `Announcer` (25 visitors), `Booster` (300 visitors) and `Publicist` (1000 visitors) badges.

Comment: Ok, so its a workaround since thats the only way the system knows. But why get rid of the Link link? I just want a link for internal SO use, not for sharing outside of SO, which was the point of the badges.

Comment: @0A0D AFAIK, "Shared" is the same as "Link" with just a bit of user tracking added.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, the "link" link worked the same as "share", minus the social buttons. Click, hit Ctrl-C. Or right click and "Copy Link Address". I don't see how it can be made more convenient, short of directly copying the link to the clipboard when clicked.

Exactly what part of the old "link" option was more convenient for you?

Comment: That I didn't have to do an extra mouse click or Ctrl+C, I could just go right click and copy it

Comment: @0A0D: But you can just right-click the `share` link too..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, isn't that nifty. I feel stupid

Comment: @0A0D: That feature is still there. Try it.

Comment: Ah, you got it, nvm..

Comment: @0A0D that's exactly what I was saying [11 minutes ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170216/getting-a-link-to-an-answer#comment503363_170216).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: sorry for being thick